# Need help on retrieving site key from dynamic website

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am creating an automated account creator using Pycharm. I am facing a problem to which I have yet to find a good solution. I want to get the site-key in order to pass the captcha to a service I have bought. I have used the requests.get method but it gives back "None" as a result. I am using selenium in my program. After some thought I realized that using requests.get method, if it worked, would bring me a different key than the one that my selenium driver is currently displayed. I googled a lot and found only that there is a module named [Selenium-Requests](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-requests/) which doesn't have Edge imported. I am using Edge as it is the only browser everyone has and doesn't require the developer version of it like Chrome and Firefox. 
Generally I haven't found a fix that can help me retrieve the key within my driver.
This is the retrieve code:

```
registerurl = requests.get(url)
registerurlstring = ''.join(str(e) for e in registerurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(registerurlstring, features="html5lib")
hidden_tags = soup.find({"id":"recaptcha-token"})
sitekey = hidden_tags
try:
  print('Sitekey = ', sitekey)
except:
  print('Sitekey = Not Found')
```

Comment: Please share your url to check why this isn't working?

Comment: My url is given based on user input, and its server variants of this: https://signup.eune.leagueoflegends.com/en/signup/

Comment: I can't see such tag the web-page you have provided?

Comment: You need to go to the Username/Password/Confirm password text

Comment: The answer you provided was pitch perfect with a bit of tweaking I managed to get it working :D

Comment: Thing is that I was not sure about your requirements which i had mention on my answer.So was bit confuse.Feel free to vote and accept this solution if this helps future reader.Thanks.

Comment: You are the best, now only thing I need to do is find how to post the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is what you are after or not.To get the  `recaptcha` value which is inside `iframe` so you have to target that `src` value of that `iframe` and using python **request** module you can get value of that input.

[image]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=6Lc3HAsUAAAAACsN7CgY9MMVxo2M09n_e4heJEiZ&co=aHR0cHM6Ly9zaWdudXAuZXVuZS5sZWFndWVvZmxlZ2VuZHMuY29tOjQ0Mw..&hl=en&v=A1Aard-wURuGsXRGA7JMOqVO&theme=dark&size=invisible&badge=bottomright&cb=ezyy1frci5ms'
registerurl = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(registerurl.text, features="html5lib")
hidden_tags = soup.find('input' ,attrs={"id":"recaptcha-token"})
print(hidden_tags['value'])
```

**Output**:

```
03AOLTBLQFd9hdHGmOesrT0xDcA8MkI6FGIiM3892Uws3aEWzPxUT8-U8IBEZHYzUEba2Jp9m3s9z_sz_fuij9OXZHABulFrI8YCD95kXV_H6xTO9vOubuZfzscleb6fdkkAE3IwUUSdTzPbXILy6SGLPI3LpPUptC1enZLIkQxQq9T8AEPPvCIsVgGe4jSE_l1jCWIRmBeBXsLgPLABZSq6ah6QWFfAngdC1rQaLMKWzLBmzh6ytEEGNYHmEG7P6UVtYcTI1IRIvq-ba-oGIUS1ELUb-1d3upQ29JWBtQ2t7_VNn237fguztf_FUDEHnAfHppUsrz-ZlkE00sMXFCuQ1XF6Qz7lH2j5g2z5KZQiODhRUBRRyd-ydjetz053bKRcgWpnNoZGNf1GBlW5inL9AtyYTkpruttw5sruAPuVgs5mrniQ5hrHNvfDIZKX905T2E21W2DsW1_07rItFYa-zkylMU83YXRQ
```

Hope this helps.

---

Updated code to get the `iframe` `src` value using `webdriver`.

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://signup.eune.leagueoflegends.com/en/signup/index")
url=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[role='presentation']").get_attribute('src')
registerurl = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(registerurl.text, features="html5lib")
hidden_tags = soup.find('input' ,attrs={"id":"recaptcha-token"})
print(hidden_tags['value'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man!
EDIT: I get the following error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: How can I make the url dynamic? Do I need to get the CSS Selector of the iframs src?

Comment: @SneakyKiwi : You can get that iframe if you use webdriver(selenium) and then get the src value.Using request you can't get that src value from the url.You have to manually copy from DOM.

Comment: the token I get is the same token as the webdriver has? I am confused in that part only.